# c# - how to connect a remote site collection programatically

Tags: 2013

Is it possible, if yes how, to connect from a webpart I coded which is installed on server A, to Server B. Like now I use SPSite, SPWeb to open local sites. What if I want to access data/properties of other sites on a different server? Data I meant custom lists, libraries, info I meant properties of the target site collection/sub site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean another SharePoint farm, then you must use the SharePoint Remote API. These consist of CSOM/JSOM/REST. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn268594.aspx

Comment: I'm new to all these stuff and trying to understand. So if topology is like this one here in the graphic. Web Tier, these two servers can see each other and communicate easily without CSOM/JSOM/REST? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee805948.aspx

Comment: Those tiers are considered one farm. So you will not need to use any Remote API. You can still use the server object model (SPWeb...) to communicate across those servers.